# Сохранение zip файла из ответа Post запроса.

Tags: c#

Отправляю Post запрос на сервер, в ответ сервер возвращает zip архив.

Вот что сейчас пробую, но код не рабочий....

```
byte[] dataArray = await data.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
request.ContentLength = dataArray.Length;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

var dataStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();
dataStream.Write(dataArray, 0, dataArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();

var resp = await request.GetResponseAsync();
dataStream = resp.GetResponseStream();

Stream receiveStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
var responseText = readStream.ReadToEnd();
Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" +    "test.zip);
Response.Write(responseText);
Response.End();
```

Возвращает поврежденный архив, если сменить расширение файла на xml.
То внутри него:

PK    qqI]J��k   l   # $ ekb_2983_20161117_16030588(res).xml
         (���@�(���@�(���@�{�{��}En�BYjQqf~�������Bj^r~Jf^��RiI�����/�MQjqiN�BZfNj^bn��RjvR����q��������y����������H�)EE���y%�J@#�� PK-     qqI]J��k   l   # $               ekb_2983_20161117_16030588(res).xml
         (���@�(���@�(���@�PK      u   �

Перепробовал различные варианты, но так рабочего варианта не смог получить.

Comment: А почему в Response данные пишутся как текст?

Comment: Да я уже по разному пробывал, этот кусок кода один из вариантов который сейчас я как пример использовал.

Comment: Попробуйте поставить `Encoding.ASCII` вместо `Encoding.UTF8` А вообще `StreamReader`-обвертка мне тут не нравится, может можно как-то без нее. Может лучше через `MemoryStream` сделать... Или вообще через `byte[]` прочесть и записать.

Comment: Попробуйте `BinaryReader` вместо `StreamReader`.

Comment: BinaryReader вообще пустоту возвращает...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то у вас всё сложно. Попробуйте так:

```
using (var resp = await request.GetResponseAsync())
using (var file = File.Create(path))
using (var responseStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
{
    await responseStream.CopyToAsync(file);
}
```

Comment: Данный вариант тоже пробовал, но файл создается почему то пустой. Данный вариант один из первых пробовал. Уже голова скоро взорвется )))

Comment: @Macro: А вы точно пробовали **именно** так, с `using`? Без него будет пустой файл.

Comment: Признаю данный косяк, с using все заработало. Просто сейчас призадумался почему именно так, если другие методы работают в контроллере mvc без using ))

Comment: @Macro: Потому что реальная запись происходит при закрытии потока (для маленьких файлов). Без using поток остаётся незакрытым, и запись не происходит.

Comment: Теперь чуточку усложнилась задача, а как на лету разархивировать?

Comment: Вот попробовал вариант:

Comment: using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
            using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (FileStream targetStream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Report/" + fn + ".xml"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                using (GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    decompressionStream.CopyTo(targetStream);
                }
            }

Comment: @Macro: Разархивирование — это уже отдельная проблема. Лучше задать отдельный вопрос, хорошо?